# Symlink Linking Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, capistrano

I am trying to symlink the public folder to my rails application to the public_html folder on my server and I can't seem to get it right.

I have a task in my deploy.rb file called `:link_release_to_public`:

```
namespace :deploy do 
  task :link_release_to_public do
    run "cd ~"
    run "rm -rf ~/public_html"
    run "ln -sf ~/#{current_path}/public ~/public_html"
  end
end
```

In it, I remove the existing "public_html" folder and then create the symlink using the command:

```
ln -sf ~/rails_app/releases/current/public ~/public_html
```

The goal is to replace ~/public_html with a symlink to the public folder of the current release.

Running `cap deploy:link_release_to_public` completes successfully, however, rather than getting the files linked directly into the ~/public_html folder, it creates the "public_html" folder and then symlinks "public" inside ~/public_html so that: `~/public_html/public`.

If I do the exact same steps in the task directly on the server (via SSH) it works perfectly.  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure , that the same command via ssh creates what you expect ?

Comment: Yes.  I have copied the commands letter by letter into the terminal and confirmed it works.

Comment: In this case there is no reason the same command to refuse to work in your `deploy.rb' .

Comment: That's why it is so frustrating.  Just to be sure, I ran cap `deploy:link_release_to_public` once again.  I copied the commands that are listed when the task is run and pasted them into the terminal over SSH.  It worked on the server, did not work with capistrano.

Comment: In situations like this you have to be cool and patient . Just split the big problem in little pieces and take small steps . For example: try to remove a couple of commands in your `deploy.rb` , like `run cd ~` and `rm -rf ...` .

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement.  I worked through the task by commenting out all but one command so that `deploy:link_release_to_public` only did one step at a time.  `run "cd ~"` and `run "rm -rf ~/public_html"` worked as expected.  `ln -s ~/rails_app/releases/current/public ~/public_html` did not.  That would lead me to believe that there is a problem with the way capistrano is issuing that command to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem is in how the commands are put into the task.  I changed the task so that the remove and symlink command were issued at the same time rather than separately:

```
namespace :deploy do 
  task :link_release_to_public do
    run "cd ~"
    run "rm -rf ~/public_html && ln -sf ~/#{current_path}/public ~/public_html"
  end
end
```

I ran the command and it worked as expected by putting a symlink as ~/public_html.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
ln -sf ~/rails_app/releases/current/public/ ~/public_html
```

Notice the slash at the end of `...current/public/` . It instructs the `ln` command to make a symlink to the directory , not to create a new one and symlink it .

Comment: I tried putting the slash at the end of `...current/public/`.  It doesn't work via Capistrano but it does work over SSH.  I am running into the same problem.

Comment: I have made an experiment with `ln` command without the `-f` option (which is in case there is already symlinked dir to unlink it ) . You can try : `ln -s ~/rails_app/releases/current/public ~/public_html` .

Comment: What OS do you run on the server?

Comment: CentOS... I'm not sure which version

Comment: That's OK . The easiest solution is to skip symlinking and to point your web server to `...current/public` for simplicity.

Comment: I think I solved the problem.  It appears to be the way I write the command into the task.  If I combine the command instead of run it separately, it works.  I'll post an answer.